# JGraphT Failed to Parse Graph

Tags: jgrapht

Hi I am new to JGraphT and am trying to import a graph to work with. I have attached a sample below of the graph and the classes i have set up as the vertex and edges. Hopefully i am doing this the right way.

I am getting the error code:

### Caused by: org.jgrapht.nio.ImportException: Failed to parse GraphML

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

I would love some advice on how to sort this issue and get the graph built. Do i need a Supplier/provider? Do i need to implement a vertex set? Thank you

Vertex Class:

```
public class Node {

    private String id;
    private String lat;
    private String lon;
    private String name;
    private String waypointType;
    private String levelId;
    private String onStartingRoute;
    private String onFinishroute;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String relatedRoutes;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(String id, String lat, String lon, String name, String waypointType, String levelId, String onStartingRoute, String onFinishroute, String title, String description, String relatedRoutes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.name = name;
        this.waypointType = waypointType;
        this.levelId = levelId;
        this.onStartingRoute = onStartingRoute;
        this.onFinishroute = onFinishroute;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.relatedRoutes = relatedRoutes;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getWaypointType() {
        return waypointType;
    }

    public void setWaypointType(String waypointType) {
        this.waypointType = waypointType;
    }

    public String getLevelId() {
        return levelId;
    }

    public void setLevelId(String levelId) {
        this.levelId = levelId;
    }

    public String getOnStartingRoute() {
        return onStartingRoute;
    }

    public void setOnStartingRoute(String onStartingRoute) {
        this.onStartingRoute = onStartingRoute;
    }

    public String getOnFinishroute() {
        return onFinishroute;
    }

    public void setOnFinishroute(String onFinishroute) {
        this.onFinishroute = onFinishroute;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRelatedRoutes() {
        return relatedRoutes;
    }

    public void setRelatedRoutes(String relatedRoutes) {
        this.relatedRoutes = relatedRoutes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", lat='" + lat + '\'' +
                ", lon='" + lon + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", waypointType='" + waypointType + '\'' +
                ", levelId='" + levelId + '\'' +
                ", onStartingRoute='" + onStartingRoute + '\'' +
                ", onFinishroute='" + onFinishroute + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", relatedRoutes='" + relatedRoutes + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return toString().hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return (o instanceof Node)&&(toString().equals(o.toString()));
    }
}
```

Edge Class:

```
public class Edge {

    private String edgeId;
    private String weight;
    private String alpha;
    private String intendedpathlonlat;
    private String levelId;
    private String type;

    public Edge() {
    }

    public Edge(String edgeId, String weight, String alpha, String intendedpathlonlat, String levelId, String type) {
        this.edgeId = edgeId;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.alpha = alpha;
        this.intendedpathlonlat = intendedpathlonlat;
        this.levelId = levelId;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getEdgeId() {
        return edgeId;
    }

    public void setEdgeId(String edgeId) {
        this.edgeId = edgeId;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }

    public void setAlpha(String alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public String getIntendedpathlonlat() {
        return intendedpathlonlat;
    }

    public void setIntendedpathlonlat(String intendedpathlonlat) {
        this.intendedpathlonlat = intendedpathlonlat;
    }

    public String getLevelId() {
        return levelId;
    }

    public void setLevelId(String levelId) {
        this.levelId = levelId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Edge{" +
                "edgeId='" + edgeId + '\'' +
                ", weight='" + weight + '\'' +
                ", alpha='" + alpha + '\'' +
                ", intendedpathlonlat='" + intendedpathlonlat + '\'' +
                ", levelId='" + levelId + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return toString().hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return (o instanceof Node)&&(toString().equals(o.toString()));
    }
}
```

Graph Class:

```
public class Graph {

    private GraphMLImporter<Node, Edge> graphMLImporter = new GraphMLImporter<>();
    private Graph<Node, Edge> venueGraph;
    private InputStream file;
    private Context context;

    public void createWayGraph(Context context) throws IOException {

        file = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("route.xml");
        graphMLImporter.setEdgeWeightAttributeName("weight");
        graphMLImporter.setSchemaValidation(true);
        graphMLImporter.importGraph(venueGraph, file);

    }
}
```

Sample - GraphML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key attr.name="weight" attr.type="double" for="edge" id="weight" />
  <key attr.name="edgeid" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="edgeid" />
  <key attr.name="alpha" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="alpha" />
  <key attr.name="intendedpathlonlat" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="intendedpathlonlat" />
  <key attr.name="levelid" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="levelid" />
  <key attr.name="weight" attr.type="long" for="edge" id="weight" />
  <key attr.name="type" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="type" />
  <key attr.name="relatedroutes" attr.type="string" for="node" id="relatedroutes" />
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="node" id="description" />
  <key attr.name="title" attr.type="string" for="node" id="title" />
  <key attr.name="on_finish_route" attr.type="string" for="node" id="on_finish_route" />
  <key attr.name="on_starting_route" attr.type="string" for="node" id="on_starting_route" />
  <key attr.name="level_id" attr.type="string" for="node" id="level_id" />
  <key attr.name="waypoint_type" attr.type="string" for="node" id="waypoint_type" />
  <key attr.name="name" attr.type="string" for="node" id="name" />
  <key attr.name="lon" attr.type="string" for="node" id="lon" />
  <key attr.name="lat" attr.type="string" for="node" id="lat" />
  <graph edgedefault="directed" id="Station">
    <node id="L08-022">
      <data key="lat">40.69330963</data>
      <data key="lon">-73.98752537</data>
      <data key="name" />
      <data key="waypoint_type">escalator</data>
      <data key="level_id">1080000</data>
      <data key="on_starting_route" />
      <data key="on_finish_route" />
    </node>
    <node id="L08-023">
      <data key="lat">40.69318355</data>
      <data key="lon">-73.98755793</data>
      <data key="name" />
      <data key="waypoint_type">stairs</data>
      <data key="level_id">1080000</data>
      <data key="on_starting_route" />
      <data key="on_finish_route" />
    </node>
    <node id="L08-024">
      <data key="lat">40.69316844</data>
      <data key="lon">-73.98755873</data>
      <data key="name" />
      <data key="waypoint_type">stairs</data>
      <data key="level_id">1080000</data>
      <data key="on_starting_route" />
      <data key="on_finish_route" />
    </node>
 <edge source="WL10-054" target="L10-029">
      <data key="type">floor</data>
      <data key="weight">4.22</data>
      <data key="levelid">1100000</data>
      <data key="intendedpathlonlat">[[-73.9874098324427, 40.6923649788941], [-73.9873852113531, 40.6923542068882], [-73.9874280729066, 40.6923105568907], [-73.9874317515063, 40.6923068106214], [-73.9874565632741, 40.692323527741], [-73.9874098324427, 40.6923649788941]]</data>
      <data key="alpha">0.0</data>
      <data key="edgeid">RL10-059</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="WL10-054" target="WL10-053">
      <data key="type">floor</data>
      <data key="weight">5.69</data>
      <data key="levelid">1100000</data>
      <data key="intendedpathlonlat">[[-73.9875185331049, 40.6923375058386], [-73.9875194277605, 40.6923108807062], [-73.9874887802005, 40.6923107720732], [-73.9874280729066, 40.6923105568907], [-73.987427278228, 40.6923378450122], [-73.9875185331049, 40.6923375058386]]</data>
      <data key="alpha">0.0</data>
      <data key="edgeid">RL10-060</data>
    </edge>
</graph>
</graphml>
```

Comment: The error indicates that there's something wrong with the graphml file you are trying to load. Have you tried to validate/check the XML file for compliance with the graphml format? Have you tested a different graph? The example you are showing is already quite elaborate. If you are new to jgrapht I would definitely start with a much smaller problem, without custom edges, and test whether that works. Various examples can be found in the test classes: https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/tree/master/jgrapht-io/src/test/java/org/jgrapht/nio/graphml

Comment: @JorisKinable Thank you for taking the time to look at this, I will check the GraphML document again, It has been produced by QGIS so i am sure it should Be OK. I understand your advice and i completely agree, however this is the task i have been set, in at the deep-end! if there is anyway if you have experience you could look at this for me i would be really appreciative i have been stalled for a few days now. Thanks for your advice Joris.